# Multi-store & CMS pages

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, cms

I have a multi-store magento install and I am trying to find out how can I assign a CMS page to multiple store.

I created a CMS page which is let say FAQ. Accessible from `store1.com/faq`.
I want the exact same page to be accessible from `store2.com/faq`.

How can I do that via the backend?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Below, I cant see any `Store View` selection.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit your CSM page and in the `Store View` multiselect chooses the store views you want.

Comment: that s the issue i think. I do not see any "Store View" when I edit the cms page.

Comment: that's strange. If you have multiple store views you should see the store view selector. Maybe you have some extension that affects the cms.

Comment: That s a brand new install of magento.

Comment: Here is the form block that should show the store view selector: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Main.php#L87.  Are you sure you have more than one store view in your instance?

Comment: Yes pretty sure.

Comment: Anything special to set to become in multiple store mode ?

Comment: You just have to add one more store view. [You can see here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php#L635) that isSingleStore returns true if you have less than 3 store views. and you have one store view for admin and one for frontend. If you add a second one for frontend you should have 3 store views and isSingleStore should return false.

Comment: even if I add 4 stores and 1 new view for each new store, it wont show me that list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30531/discussion-between-user2360915-and-marius).